# Tor active link status checker

Tags: python, vb.net, linker, tor

Below is the code it's giving an error I don't know why and we also need to convert this code into vb.net

```
#Tor Onion links Active Status checking
import os
import requests
import JSON
import time
import subprocess

class TorActivation:
    def __ini__(self):
        pass

    def StartTor(self):
        subprocess.Popen([f"{os.getcwd()}\\Tor\\tor.exe"])
        time.sleep(10)
        print("Tor Proxy has been started!!")
        print("Starting Process of Checking")

    def proxy_build(self):
        try:
            self.proxies = {
            'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
            'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
            }
            print("proxy setup is succefully done")
    
        except:
            print("Tor is not activated, please rerun the program!!!")
    

    def check(self,onion,save):
        print()
        try:
            data = requests.get(f"http://{onion}",proxies=self.proxies)
            status=data.status_code
        except:
            status=404
        if status==200:
            print(f"{onion} : Active")
            print(f"Status Code : {status}")
        else:
            print(f"{onion} : nonActive")
            print(f"Status Code : {status}")

        if save==True:
            w=open("Status.txt","a")
            if status==200:
                w.write(f"http://{onion} : Active")
            else:
                w.write(f"http://{onion} : nonActive")
            w.close()
        print()
        return 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    run=TorActivation()
    run.StartTor()
    run.proxy_build()
    while True:
        print("1. Single Url Checking")
        print("2. Multiplt Url Checking")
        print("3. Quit")
        option=input("Enter your option: ")
        if str(option)=='1':
            onion=input("Enter the url: ")
            run.check(onion,False)
        elif str(option)=='2':
            filename=input("Enter the txt filename: ")
            f=open(filename, "a")
            f.readlines()
            for x in f:
                x=x.rstrip("\n")
                run.check(x,True)
            f.close()
        elif option=='3':
            break
```

Comment: So, you didn't tell what error, and if it gives error, and why would you want to convert something that doesn't work -- and that's not even a question, or are you expecting someone to both fix your code and convert it for you?

Comment: I have made it working I want someone wo help me convert this code into vb.net as I haven't used vb so that's why